# How to count how many times an user input was wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a game and want to go through all questions. If the users answer is wrong, I want to know how many times this happened.

I've a little problem with this code. When I run everything, The first and second functions runs correctly. But when I want to print x_errors, It says that "name 'answer' is not defined". I don't understand because in my code the 'answer' is "10", "20", and "30". Hope someone can help me understand this better. I appreciate all the help!

The code:

```
def question():
    input_question("How old are Ring?", "10")
    input_question("How old are King?", "20")
    input_question("How old are Bing?", "30")

def input_question(question, answer):
    print(question)
    user_answer = input("Your answer: ")
    wrong = 0
    while user_answer != answer:
        wrong = 1
        print("Try again")
        user_answer = input("Your answer: ")
    print("Correct!")
    return wrong

question()
x_errors = input_question(question, answer)
print(x_errors)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the part of you code that you declared `answer`?

Comment: "in my code the 'answer' is "10", "20", and "30"" <- not in the code you have shown us. There is not a single line in there that sets the variable `answer` to a value.

Comment: This has to do with global vs. local variables.

Comment: Aha, so that is the problem. I'm new to Python so you know.. But i thought that the question() have both the parameters question and answer in input_question(question, answer). How should I declare answer then? How do I set answer to the value "10", "20" and "30"? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, even if you declare `answer` you'll have a problem with passing `question` as argument, because it will pass the object of your function `question` and I don't think this is what you're intending to do. Can you edit your question to explain your desired value for your `x_error` variable?

Comment: I am making a game and want to go through all questions. If the users answer is wrong, the variable wrong should be = 1 and then I want to return it and use it in another function. Therefore I did this --> x_errors = input_question(question, answer) <-- as an example so I can take x_errors and use it in another function where I calculate how many times the user wrote wrong

Comment: So you should be getting the return values from your `input_question` calls inside your `question` function.

Comment: Do you want the overall count of how many times the user got it wrong (despite the question), or do you want to count for each separate question?

Comment: Yes that's my goal but I don't know how to do that because I haven't declared 'answer'. I want so that the function count for each seperate question

Comment: If x_errors holds the number of times that the user worte a wrong answer in input_question(), then you should edit input_question() in order to count the number of times that the user wrote a wrong answer.

Comment: You won't accomplish your goal by simply declaring answer, you have to implement your wrong answer count mechanism inside your `input_question` because is only there that you can know how many times your user got it wrong. Than your function can return this amount and you can do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I thought. But when I have the variable x_errors, can I insert it in the function question() and after each question type for example nr1_x_errors = x_errors? Then the nr1_x_errors will be the wrong amount of the question number 1. And in the end I can return the sum of nr1_x_errors, nr2_x_errors and nr3_x_errors

Comment: .. but my problem is that I cant type --> x_errors = input_question(question, answer) <-- that is my problem

Comment: That's the thing we're trying to explain to you, your problem is not to fix `x_errors = input_question(question, answer)` because even if you can make it execute without your interpreter signing error, doing this won't help you to accomplish what you're trying to do. I got what you're trying to do and I edited your question to reflect this and I gave you a code as an answer that I hope will make it clear to you what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The error "name answer is not defined" comes from this line :

```
x_errors = input_question(question, answer)
```

The variable answer is not defined at the moment the function is called. Also, the question will be an object representing the method question() that you declared at the begining of your code instead of a string.

From what I've understood, since you call the method question() which also calls input_question() three times with the questions and the expected answers, then, there is no need to call input_question as you did at the end of your file. Your code must look like this :

```
def question():
    x_errors = input_question("How old are Ring?", 10) #remove the quote on the answer
    print (x_errors)
    x_errors = input_question("How old are King?", 20)
    print (x_errors)
    x_errors = input_question("How old are Bing?", 30)
    print (x_errors)

def input_question(question, answer):
    print(question)
    user_answer = input("Your answer: ")
    wrong = 0
    while user_answer != answer:
        wrong+=1
        print("Try again")
        user_answer = input("Your answer: ")
    print("Correct!")
    return wrong

question()
#x_errors = input_question(question, answer)
#print(x_errors)
```

Comment: What you have done in the function question() is the way I would do it. But when I run the program I can't get a correct answer because the numbers (10, 20, 30) is int

Comment: Thank u. I run the code in Python and it works (in my way :*D). I changed back the numbers (10, 20, 30) to string because I will have questions which is letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your wrong answer count mechanism inside your `input_question` and keep a global count of wrong answers in your `question` function:

```
def question():
    questions = [
        ("How old are Ring?", "10"),
        ("How old are King?", "20"),
        ("How old are Bing?", "30"),
    ]
    global_wrong_count = 0
    for text, answer in questions:
        global_wrong_count += input_question(text, answer)
    return global_wrong_count


def input_question(question, answer):
    print(question)
    user_answer = input("Your answer: ")
    wrong_count = 0
    while user_answer != answer:
        wrong_count += 1
        print("Try again")
        user_answer = input("Your answer: ")
    print("Correct!")
    return wrong_count


print("User got it wrong {} time(s)".format(str(question())))
```

Comment: Also, if you want to have a relation of your specific questions and the wrong answer count for each of them, you can return this information from your `question` function by using some data structure that allows you to relate two values (eg: a `dict`).

Comment: PS: The only place you can count the wrong answers is inside your `input_question`, because is only there that you know when a user get it wrong. You can't have this information later if you don't save any kind of information about it.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed. I appreciate your work. Now I'm trying to understand some parts of your code!